# Can't install Ruby 2.2.0 using rbenv

Tags: git, ruby

I installed `rbenv` from GitHub:

```
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

I’m trying to install Ruby 2.2.0:

```
sudo /home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin/rbenv install 2.2.0
```

How can I fix it?

Here are the last lines from the log:

```
installing bundle gems:       /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
/tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- zlib (LoadError)
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/package.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20150209193236.15392/ruby-2.2.0/lib/rubygems.rb:556:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:717:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:716:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have zlib installed. For a proper build environment, run the following:

Ubuntu/Debian:

```
apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm3 libgdbm-dev
```

CentOS/Fedora:

```
yum install -y gcc openssl-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel readline-devel zlib-devel gdbm-devel ncurses-devel
```

For more, read [the `ruby-build` wiki](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki).